# Significant Difference in r

Tags: r, statistics, significance

So here's my problem:

I have a bunch of data about sound production and where the emphasis falls in a word. What I'm trying to do is determine if the difference between production on stressed and unstressed syllables is significant. The problem is that when I try to use the cor() function, the data sets aren't the same length. I have about 500 instances of stressed syllables, but only 400 of unstressed syllables. I'm very new to r, but here's the code I've attempted:

```
data <- read.csv('D:/blaaah/Stressed.csv', header=TRUE)
var1 <- data$intdiff
data <- read.csv('D:/blaaah/Unstressed.csv', header=TRUE)
var2 <- data$intdiff
cor(var1, var2)
```

Of course, I get an error because the data sets are different lengths. So how do I check for significance between the sets without having them be the same length?

Thanks a bunch!

P.S. Just ask if my question isn't clear. I'm afraid I sometimes assume everyone knows what I'm doing...

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what your two vectors represent, but if they are signals then look up "cross-correlation".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using cor() would be appropriate if you expected there to be a relationship between *var1* and *var2*, for instance if you'd expect the value of an item in *var2* to be larger if the corresponding item in *var1* is larger. There is a difficulty when the data sets are not the same length, because there are no corresponding items to compare once you get past the end of the shorter dataset.

I think, in this case, that a comparison of the two data sets to establish if their means are different is more likely to be useful to you. For that, you'd want to use a t test, as described, with examples in R, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15724/how-to-compare-group-means-for-two-samples-with-t-test-using-r). You'd also want to confirm that the assumptions for using the t test are valid for this case, e.g. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test).

Comment: Yes! A 2 sample t-test was far more appropriate. Thank you!